# How can losing 2FA render encrypted data inaccessible?

Tags: encryption, multi-factor

As per [Bitwarden's FAQ](https://bitwarden.com/help/article/lost-two-step-device/#dont-have-a-recovery-code)

> If you don’t have your Recovery Code saved somewhere outside of your Vault, there is unfortunately no way for the team to recover the account or data therein. You’ll need to delete your account and start a new one.

I understand that losing the master password renders the data encrypted with it inaccessible, but 2FA is merely an authentication method, or can that actually be used for partial encryption as well? Or does this statement merely mean the Bitwarden team *won't* provide access on the basis that e.g. they cannot verify you're the one actually supposed to have the "lost" 2FA?

The question is not about Bitwarden specifically but rather about whether there are actually means to use 2FA for encryption purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the second factor used. *(EDIT: Note that this answer is generic to 2FA for encryption in general, and not specific to BitWarden; I don't know enough about how their 2FA works to say.)*

Some, like TOTP or other one-time passwords, can't be used ahead of time as an input to the encryption, so in that case it's a "won't" rather than a "can't". (Their software might just not *support* them accessing the vault using the password but without providing the second factor, but software that does support it could be written and would work.)

Others, like key files or private keys embedded in security devices (e.g. Yubikeys, smart cards, etc.), can be directly used in the decryption process. For example, a key file or public key can be used to encrypt the vault encryption key, such that the vault simply can't be decrypted again without having the same key file or corresponding private key to decrypt the vault key. In that case, the vault key is protected by two keys: the one derived from your password (something you know), and the one derived from the key in your second factor (something you have).

Answer (score 1):

It's against the privacy policy of any organization to issue data to any user that claims to be a legitimate owner of any information, but can't truly verify his/her identity using the additional 2FA feature which he/she chose during registration as a form of service access. To protect the actual users, the data is therefore not issued to any person or bot that tries to access it and can't verify it using the 2FA feature enabled, hence, even if you the owner lost the recovery code, there won't be any way that they'll be able to tell that it is truly you(the) owner trying to access the data.

Put it simply, it is just an extra form of MFA security to help protect any user if for example in a situation where your normal login data has been compromised by third party users(username and password) which is enough to give them access to your data, but since theirs an extra security added, they'd have to verify the ownership other than just providing the normal username and password.

Answer (score 1):

The same FAQ talks about getting sent an email AND that losing access to your linked Email inbox is the same as losing your 2FA device.

That suggests that the TOTP code is not part of the encryption process, but rather, as the FAQ states, it will

> lock you out of your Bitwarden Vault